# Final velocity and length of a projectile impacting and passing through a target slab?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision, projectile, drag

I want to know the approximate final velocity $v_f$ and length $L_f$ of a projectile that impacts and passes through a slab of given thickness $D$.

This is my attempt to solve the problem so far. I first assume that the relation for penetration depth into a semi-infinite slab is given by:
$$
x_f = bL_0 \frac{av_0^2}{av_0^2 + b}
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are constants depending on the material parameters of the projectile and target and the shape of the projectile, $L_0$ is the projectile's initial length, $v_0$ is its impact velocity, and $x_f$ is the final penetration depth, which is reached when either $v$ or $L$ becomes zero. This is the simplest equation I could find which matches the hydrodynamic approximation at large $v$ and has correct low-velocity behavior, for suitable choices of $a$ and $b$ (see below). I'm aware there is a similar question that assumes a rigid, unchanging projectile, but my experience trying to solve this indicates that having a varying length $L$ adds a significant challenge, and I have not been able to find a solution.

One thing I am not sure about is whether I need to separately specify how $L$ changes as the projectile penetrates. If so, I want the equation for the projectile erosion to asymptote to $\partial{L}/\partial{x}=-1/b$ in the hydrodynamic (high-velocity) limit and $\partial{L}/\partial{x}=0$ as $v$ approaches zero. One simple possibility is to assume the projectile length erodes according to:
$$
\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial{x}} = -\frac{1}{b}\frac{av^2}{av^2+b}
$$
but I don't know if this is even approximately correct.

How do I transform this information into the solutions I'm looking for? I'm hoping to find approximate solutions with the correct low- and high-velocity behavior, that don't require numerically integrating differential equations, because I want a computer to be able to solve many instances of this problem very quickly. If anyone knows of a more amenable and straightforward set of approximations to solve this problem I would be grateful for that answer as well.

EDIT: Here is more information about how I got to the first equation for $x_f$. First at very low velocities I assume the projectile remains rigid, so its mass $m$ and length $L=L_0$ are constant. Also at very low velocities, the dominant term of the resistive force on the projectile from the target should be a constant $F$, so $\text{d}E = -F\text{d}x$ yields that $x_f$ is proportional to $mv^2$. $m =  \rho_p A L_0$ so I absorb $\rho_p$ and $A$ as well as anything to do with $F$ into the constant $a$, leaving $x_f = aL_0 v^2$. At very high velocities, I assume the pressure due to impact is much greater than the shear moduli of the projectile and target so they behave as liquids. I then looked up the hydrodynamic approximation of impact depth, which gives $x_f = L_0\sqrt{\frac{\rho_p}{\rho_t}}$ and I set $b = \sqrt{\frac{\rho_p}{\rho_t}}$ where $\rho_p$ and $\rho_t$ are the densities of projectile and target respectively. In this limit $x_f$ is constant with respect to $v$. The equation I gave above for $x_f$ smoothly interpolates between these limits, so I hope it will be at least a decent approximation.

However, the second equation for $\partial{L}/\partial{x}$ is much closer to a wild guess on my part. I'm fairly confident that $\partial{L}/\partial{x} = - 1/b$ in the hydrodynamic limit, but I don't know what the low-velocity behavior should be.

EDIT 2: Since this has gone for a while with no answers, if there is some reason why the question can't be answered I'd like to know that as well (i.e., if there is no solution, an answer explaining why not).

Comment: *I first assume that the relation for penetration depth into a semi-infinite slab is given by* What lead you to that assumption?

Comment: At low velocities, the dominant resistive force on the projectile should be constant, so _dE = -Fdx_ gives that the penetration depth is proportional to _mv^2_.  I'm assuming that the projectile remains approximately rigid at sufficiently low speeds, (so _m_ and _L_ don't change in this limit). I express this as _aLv^2_, where _a_ contains a factor of _rho*A_ so _rho*A*L = m_.

Comment: At high velocities, I looked up the hydrodynamic approximation, which assumes the projectile is a fluid jet that collides with a fluid target. Here, it seems that the impact depth _x_ depends on _L_ times the square root of the ratio of the projectile to target densities, and doesn't depend on _v_. I define _b_ as the square root of the density ratio. The above equation matches both limiting cases, it is smooth, and I can't think of a simpler formula with those properties, so I hoped it would be a decent starting approximation for my purposes. @Gert

Comment: Just to clarify, _a_ also contains other factors besides _rho*A_, such as the resistance pressure from the target. As for the hydrodynamic approximation, it should be good when the velocity is so large that the impact pressure greatly exceeds the shear moduli of the projectile and target, so they may as well be fluids, which is why I used it as my high-speed limit.

Comment: Very nice. Maybe it would have been better to include all that in the question?

Comment: @Gert Ok, I will add it in an edit.

Comment: I've made some progress myself on this question since posting it: I still am not close to answering it, but this progress might help someone else answer it. Should I add additional information to the question or place it in comments? (I'm new to StackExchange so I'm not sure what the common practice is).

Comment: You can have a situation where an object moving through a material instead accumulates material as it moves through the slab, though in the case of a fast projectile I'd assume also that the velocity is more likely to just part the slab material instead.

Comment: @Triatticus I had not considered that the projectile might _accumulate_ material; interesting. Perhaps I should clarify, by length _L_ I mean the part of the projectile that is still intact, so material accumulated from the target and material eroded from the front of the projectile don't count. Also, by _v_ I mean the velocity of the projectile's rear, not it's front (which may be eroding or accumulating as it travels). Basically, I'm willing to ignore the eroded and accumulated bits in the interest of simplicity and faster computation.

Comment: @Triatticus Another way to think of it might be, that I expect the accumulated and eroded material won't be structurally sound. So, when the projectile exits the slab that material will probably separate from the main body of the projectile, and form a cluster of smaller separate projectiles. I'm hoping to be able to ignore this or at least make it a separate subprocess of the simulation I'm trying to create.